# Python3 deltatime as string for file search

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to search a file for yesterdays date, and save the line to another file. When I put the date in to search "8/25/2020" everything works fine.  When I pull the current date, then subtract 1 day it doesn't work when adding it to line.startswith(). What am I doing wrong? Also I had to format the year as %y%y because the dates in the file are the full year not the last 2 digits. Thankfully its 2020.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

yesterday = (datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m/%d/%y%y")
print(yesterday)

def check():
    with open("1.txt", "r") as f, open("2.txt", "w") as e:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(yesterday):
                e.write(line)
                print(line)

check()
```

Comment: Use `%Y` for a four-digit year, not `%y%y`.

Comment: Thank you for the date format.  Still trying to figure out the search issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting multiple ways to get the code to work I finally figured out the issue.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

yesterday = (datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%-m/%d/%Y" + ":")
print(yesterday)

def check_data():
    with open("1.txt", "r") as f, open("2.txt", "w") as e:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(yesterday):
                e.write(line)
                print(line)
check_data()
```

I needed to remove the 0 padding in the date.  %-m/%d/%Y  -m in the date format fixed the issue.

Comment: note that this won't work on all platforms. a `lstrip('0')` might be the safe option.